# Redirecting from apache2 to tomcat on Ubuntu 16.04 results in tomcat-generated 404

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, tomcat8, mod-proxy

I have set up mod_proxy on Apache2 (2.4.18) to a tomcat (8.5.28) JSF application - both on the same Ubuntu (16.04) machine. This is *almost* working as I can see the redirect taking place, however tomcat is returning an unexpected 404.

Some history: I have done all the usual stuff of enabling the mod_proxy modules with sudo a2enmod proxy, proxy_http, proxy_ajp, rewrite, deflate, headers, proxy_balancer, proxy_connect, proxy_html and yes, I have restarted apache2.

My website is www.goodfoodwaiheke.org (a not-for-profit food cooperative)

In Apache2 I have set up the virtual host file /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/goodfoodwaiheke.org.conf with this content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.goodfoodwaiheke.org

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/coop
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/coop
</VirtualHost>
```

I have enabled the virtual host with sudo e2ensite goodfoodwaiheke.org

In the browser I go to http://www.goodfoodwaiheke.org. The redirection from Apache2 to Tomcat seems to work because the browser's url changes to http://www.goodfoodwaiheke.org/coop/. This is fine because the deployed (working) Tomcat application is in coop.war. However, I get an Apache Tomcat generated 404 error. The message is "/coopcoop/" and the description is "The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

If I use the browser on the Ubuntu box to go to the proxy pass address (http://localhost:8080/coop) it invokes the JSF application ok. I feel there may be a clue in the 404 message where it reports "/coopcoop/". That is almost certainly why a 404 is being returned, but I have no idea why it is trying to  access a 'coopcoop' resource.

I've tried pretty much everything I can think of and I'd be grateful for any hints.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working and am posting in case it helps others. I put a / at the end of the ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse addresses. I also defined ServerAlias as goodfoodwaiheke.org (i.e. without the www).